# Toggling buttons on click

Tags: javascript, jquery

Whenever a button is clicked, the following need to be performed:

1. All siblings of the clicked button get toggled
2. All `edit_button` get toggled, except for the `edit_button` within the same span as the clicked button (note: the excluded `edit_button` can be the same as the clicked button)

The JavaScript is working in the way I want it to, but I am curious if there's another better way to achieve the second requirement.

Note: `save_button` and `cancel_button` are hidden when first loaded.

```js
$(function() {
  $('.edit_button, .save_button, .cancel_button').click(function() {
    $(this).toggle();
    $(this).siblings('button').toggle();
    $('div#personal_info').find('button.edit_button').not($(this).parent().find('button.edit_button')).toggle();
  });
});
```

```html
<div id="personal_info">
  <div id="section_1">
    <span><button class="edit_button">Edit</button><button class="cancel_button">Cancel</button><button class="save_button">Save Changes</button></span>
  </div>
  <div id="section_2">
    <span><button class="edit_button">Edit</button><button class="cancel_button">Cancel</button><button class="save_button">Save Changes</button></span>
  </div>
  <div id="section_3">
    <span><button class="edit_button">Edit</button><button class="cancel_button">Cancel</button><button class="save_button">Save Changes</button></span>
  </div>
</div>
```

Answer (score 2, accepted):

The selector for all `edit_buttons` can be expressed as a single selector `$('div#personal_info button.edit_button')`.

I am tempted to rewrite the code to use closure scope to cache the selector values e.g.

```
// Iterate using each to define cached values for selectors within a 
// closure scope 
$('.edit_button, .save_button, .cancel_button').each(function() {
  var button = $(this);
  // select all elements that need be toggled on click
  var toggled = $([
    button,
    button.siblings('button'),
    $('div#personal_info button.edit_button').
       not(button.parent().find('button.edit_button'))
  ]);
  // toggle each element separetely on click as the first element in a selector
  // defines the target visiblity of a no parameter .toggle()
  button.click(function() {
    toggled.each(
      function() {
        $(this).toggle();
      });
    });
});
```

The benefit of it is that less traversing is needed. Unfortunately the toggle method didn't work quite as I imagined it would when there are both hidden and shown elements in the selector when using jQuery 1.6.2.

The above [code is available through jsFiddle](http://jsfiddle.net/PZgEK/)

From a maintenance/cleanliness point of view I'm a bit wary how this piece of code merges the concerns of

1. Hiding all edit actions
2. Showing all edit actions
3. Displaying save and cancel actions for a specific edit action
4. Hiding save and cancel actions for a specific edit action

The result of all these goals leads to astonishment that is higher than the least possible. I don't really know what a good name for that function would be?

Also how and where are the event handlers for onclick events of `.save_button` and `.cancel_button` defined?

Comment: Aleksi - thx for spending your time to show and explain this alternative solution. I like the way you have outlined its pros and cons. I think I will stick with my solution plus the minor change mentioned in your first sentence. But your solution has definitely opened up my eyes to a different approach. Cheers!

Comment: Your solution helped me to learn the use of _.each_ and to get to know jsFiddle (I have been looking for a tool like this).

Comment: The sweetest words I've heard in all of stackexchange network. Thank you!